# Are subsequent pages also crawl-able (SEO) when we change route in NextJs application?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I understand that when a NextJs page is visited, server(SSR) renders and send HTML along with necessary javascript to hydrate page on client side. This make page SEO friendly.

But when we change route (say "/about"), it does not actually send HTML file but just about.js (Content-Type: application/javascript) file (and looking into file it looks like React VirtualDOM, but am not sure). And this get painted on DOM and we see about page.

[image]

So then, my question is -

1. Is this about page SEO-friendly? (because it's not HTML file)
2. If not, then does it mean only initial page is good for SEO and not subsequent routes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are asking specifically about the client-side transition with the `next/link` component.

Historically, it was important for SEO to make all your content accessible directly in the HTML generated by your SSR, because crawlers wouldn't execute javascript and couldn't see anything but what is directly returned from the server. Nowadays, some crawlers like Google can fully execute javascript and therefore see anything a user would see in their browser.

You can argue that not all crawlers do that and that there are still advantages in SSR. Luckily, NextJs gives you the best of both worlds:

When you use the `next/link` component, e.g.

```
<Link href='/about'>About Us</Link>
```

then the resulting markup you see from the server side render will be

```
<a href="/about">About Us</a>
```

If you click on the link, nextJS prevents the browser from making a request to /about (with `event.preventDefault();`) and handles the action instead with the built in router to render the new page on the client. **However, if you access /about directly (typing it into the url bar of the browser), then you will get the server-side generated response for it.**

With that in place:

- A crawler that executes javascript and also navigates by simulating click events would also be capable of reading the resulting client-side rendered content.
- A crawler that doesn't execute javascript and only looks at your content as "plain text", can still make sense of your `<a>` tags and follow them by making new requests. Client-side transitions do not happen in this case and the result will be server side rendered.

That being said, Googles documentation on how to [make your links crawlable](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/links-crawlable) seems to imply that it doesn't simulate click events on `<a>` tags, but makes a new request for the url it finds in the href attribute:

> Google cannot follow  links without an href tag or other tags that perform a links because of script events. [...] Ensure that the URL linked to by your  tag is an actual web address that Googlebot can send requests to [...]

So overall the NextJs routing is SEO-friendly, no matter how it's crawled.

Comment: Thank you. That summarise it all. I just have a follow up question - How is this way of updating DOM (after client transition) any different from what React does? I agree state/data all is handled at BE still NextJs is painting DOM using JS code
as opposed to just parsing HTML like its done traditionally (where page is refreshed). I mean this is not exactly same as static site right? (feels more like SPA).

Comment: It’s not entirely different, but it offers features out of the box that otherwise take time to implement yourself. Noteworthy is the automatic code splitting: When you load a next.js page, only the code for that specific page is loaded. That’s why you see the about.js file being loaded when navigating. In a plain React SPA without additional config, the entire app code would be loaded upon first request, just to render that one initial page. Apart from that, there isn’t anything fundamentally different.

Comment: Since next.js needs to load code every time the user navigates, it can prefetch that data for all links that are in the viewport. So most of the time, the code splitting doesn’t slow down the navigation.
You can also use normal <a> tags instead of the next/link component to avoid the client-side navigation entirely.